# Create a new cart in prestashop programatically

Tags: overriding, prestashop, cart, product

I want to know the procedure of creating a new cart in prestashop programatically.

I am in `myprestashopproject/override/controllers/admin/AdminReturnController.php`.

Here I am in `function postprocess()`.

Can anyone please help me in creating one this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create cart object and can add the products to the newly created cart by calling updateQty method of the cart object

```
$new_cart = new Cart();
$new_cart->id_currency = $this->context->cookie->id_currency;
$new_cart->id_lang = $this->context->cookie->id_lang;
$new_cart->save();

$quantity_to_add = 1; //qty you want to add
$id_product = 1; // id of the product, which you wish to add to cart
$new_cart->updateQty($quantity_to_add, $id_product);
```

if you want to add multiple products, use loop and place the above updateQty method calling code inside loop and modify accordingly

Prestashop current cart id is stored in `$this->context->cart->id` so we have to set our newly created cart object id as the current cart

```
$this->context->cookie->id_cart = $new_cart->id;
$this->context->cookie->write();
$this->context->cookie->update();
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me  , when i try var_dump($cart) , it returns null

Comment: try var_dump($new_cart) after $new_cart->save(), not $cart

Answer (score 0):

If you want to regenerate cart with id_order, use the submitReorder functionnality in ParentOrderController.

```
    $oldCart = new Cart(Order::getCartIdStatic($id_order, $this->context->customer->id));
    $duplication = $oldCart->duplicate();
    if (!$duplication || !Validate::isLoadedObject($duplication['cart'])) {
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Sorry. We cannot renew your order.');
    } elseif (!$duplication['success']) {
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Some items are no longer available, and we are unable to renew your order.');
    } else {
        $this->context->cookie->id_cart = $duplication['cart']->id;
        $context = $this->context;
        $context->cart = $duplication['cart'];
        CartRule::autoAddToCart($context);
        $this->context->cookie->write();
        if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1) {
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc');
        }
        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');
    }
```

Comment: yes , duplication of cart is a good option but can i have some code which will provide me the procedure to create a new cart.